# Integral involving trigonometric functions and a second variable

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, solution-verification

> Integrate the following:
>   $$\int_0^{\pi/2}(1+\sin\theta)^5\cos\theta dx$$

To solve this, I integrated as per usual, as shown in my work below. However, I'm now doubting myself- I'm concerned that I did this incorrectly because theta should be a separate variable from x. **Is my solution correct? If not, where did I go wrong?**

[image]

Comment: Noted. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question is misprinted, and should have $d\theta$ and not $dx$

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.